# Isolate styles in different layouts (webpack, react)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-style-loader

I have two layouts (LayoutWithShortHeader, TestLayout) and such routes:

```
export default (
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>

    <Route path="/" component={ LayoutWithShortHeader }>
      <IndexRoute component={ Index }/>
    </Route>

    <Route path="/" component={ TestLayout }>
      <Route path="ddd" component={ TestPage }/>
      <Route path="not-found" component={ NotFound }/>
    </Route>

    <Redirect from="*" to="/not-found"/>

  </Router>
);
```

When I open /ddd the page consist of TestLayout with TestPage inside.
Unfortunately, it has styles from LayoutWithShortHeader (import './layout.sass'; inside LayoutWithShortHeader) and I don't know why.

TestLayout.jsx:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

const TestLayout = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    children: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  getInitialState() {
    return {};
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default TestLayout;
```

Webpack configs:

webpack.common.config.js:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const Sprites = require('sprite-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel', 'eslint']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css']
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass?indentedSyntax']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
          'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        loader: 'expose?jQuery'
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        loader: 'expose?$'
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: function() {
    return [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 3 versions'] })];
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Netology',
      template: './src/index.html',
      scriptFilename: 'application.js'
    }),
    new Sprites({
      'source': __dirname + '/src/images/for_sprites/',
      'imgPath': __dirname + '/src/images/',
      'cssPath': __dirname + '/src/stylesheets/',
      'multiFolders': true
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname),
    alias: {
      js: 'src/javascripts',
      fonts: 'src/fonts',
      components: 'src/components'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.sass']
  }
};
```

webpack.config.js:
    'use strict';

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const friendlyFormatter = require('eslint-friendly-formatter');
let config = require('./webpack.common.config');

config.entry = [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  './src/javascripts/main.js'
];

config.output = {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  filename: 'application.js',
  publicPath: '/'
};

config.eslint = {
  formatter: friendlyFormatter
};

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
);

module.exports = config;
```

So how to isolate styles of one layout from styles of another one?

Comment: can you please share webpack.config file. Without looking at how you are bundling the styles. Its difficult to know the correct reason.

Comment: added webpack config

Comment: Can you try adding `'localIdentName=[name]-[local]'` after the *css* and before *postcss* in common webpack config  and see what happens.

Comment: appears errors:

ERROR in ./src/javascripts/global_styles.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'localIdentName=[name]-[local]' in /storage/development/netology_fronts/src/javascripts
 @ ./src/javascripts/global_styles.js 7:0-42

ERROR in ./src/javascripts/global_styles.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'localIdentName=[name]-[local]' in /storage/development/netology_fronts/src/javascripts
 @ ./src/javascripts/global_styles.js 9:0-38

ERROR in ./src/components/layouts/LayoutWithShortHeader/LayoutWithShortHeader.jsx

...

Comment: Sorry. Change `['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass?indentedSyntax']` to `'[style', 'css?localIdentName=-[name][local]', 'postcss', 'sass?indentedSyntax]'`.

Comment: no errors, but the problem still exists :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101211/discussion-between-sandeep-and-dortonway).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working for me. Add this for styles in your component.

```
   componentWillMount() {
      styles.use();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      styles.unuse();
    }
```

In your webpack config for the **sass** use the styles as following.

```
loaders: ['style/useable', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass?indentedSyntax']
```

A better solution will be to create a decorator to apply this to all the components easily.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function LazyLoadStyles(styles) {
   return (BaseComponent) => class StyledComponent extends Component {

     componentWillMount() {
       styles.use();
      }

     componentWillUnmount() {
       styles.unuse();
     }

     render() {
       return <BaseComponent {...this.props} />;
     }
  };
}

export default withStyles;
```

Then you can use it in your component like

```
import lazyLoadStyle from './LazyLoadStyles';
import st as './Page.sass'

@lazyLoadStyle(st)
class Mycomponent extends React.Component {

....
}
```

**Edit:** 
Rename conflicting .sass files to .useable.sass, and change loader like this -

```
 {
    test: /\.sass$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass?indentedSyntax']
  },
  {
     test: /\.useable.sass$/,
     loaders: ['style/useable', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass?indentedSyntax']
  },
```

Then in your all the modules that having conflicting css. You either have to use style.use() and unuse() or use the decorator provided.

Comment: No errors and styles just disappeared from the layouts. I included styles in layout like so: import styles from './layout_with_header.sass';. It's my package.json with versions of modules, may be it might help http://pastebin.com/ypurgbYt

Comment: Now I get one strange error: http://pastebin.com/Dg6ZzMzS . Styles in the file: http://pastebin.com/DQef7Nhp .
P.S. I'm trying without decorator.

Comment: Can you please mail me the files. I will try to fix and send them back. Can you send *LayoutWithShortHeader*, *TestLayout*, their sass files and *webpack.config*. Just send me the cleaned up version if you want. Its related to style loader. Will save you a lot of time.